# Also it is better to use the callback option when using setLoggedIn in order to capture the previous version of the state as the following:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-hooks

Also it is better to use the callback option when using setLoggedIn in order to capture the previous version of the state as the following:Also it is better to use the callback option when using setLoggedIn in order to capture the previous version of the state as the following:Also it is better to use the callback option when using setLoggedIn in order to capture the previous version of the state as the following:Also it is better to use the callback option when using setLoggedIn in order to capture the previous version of the state as the following:Also it is better to use the callback option when using setLoggedIn in order to capture the previous version of the state as the following:

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `useState` is returning with `[]` instead of `{}`.

You should have the following instead:

```
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
```

**+1 suggestion:**

Also it is better to use the callback option when using `setLoggedIn` in order to capture the previous version of the state as the following:

```
const handleClick = () => {
   setLoggedIn(prev => !prev);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

change `const {loggedIn, setLoggedIn} = useState(false)`

To : `const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)`

Dont use `{}` to declare useState variable and its setter function use `[]` these instead.

Comment: click the up button shows appreciation on stackoverflow lol xD

Answer (score 0):

You are destructuring the state value and change handler incorrectly. It returns a tuple so you need to get the values like this:

```
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
```